# How to generate data like my real time data?

Tags: c#, sql-server, data-mining

I have 100 records in which I applied clustering algorithms.
Now I want to increase my dataset by generating data just like my real time data with the same probabilities. Can anyone suggest me solution? preferably in C# or SQL server.
I have seen DBMonster but I don't want random, I want the data just like my sample data.
I have tried SQL Data Generator but its also taking min and max of each column and generate random.

Comment: Hi welcome to StackOverflow. You need to be more specific, and show us what you've done so far. Look at [Ask]

Answer (score 0):

Use some type of statistical modeling software to extract the distributions (mathematical models) of your existing data. [Crystal Ball](http://www.crystalballservices.com/Software/OracleCrystalBall.aspx) perhaps? Then you'll be able to generate as much 'realistic' rest data as you'll need.

Comment: Thanks @vivek, I am using sqldatagenerator but its taking only null % for a column. I am interested in some tool which can take probabilities of column values or correlation matrix of my real data and generate data on that basis?

Comment: Performing the statistical analysis to obtain a model (column probabilities, or correlation matrices) is the hard part. Given this, generating the data is pretty straightforward; usually you'd generate random values between 0 and 1, and plug them into whatever model you ended up with.

Comment: I have done the hard part. now I want some free tool that take my column value percent/ probability and generate records on that basis..

Comment: I don't know of any, but I'm sure they exist. I won't be able to bing this any better than you.